# Not able to calculate the the total value from the visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I have written the Following code for Calculation but not sure why when i am going to add another Bundle then TOTAL of Discount Getting Null and recalculate itself.

Can anyone please look into this code and let me know what i have done wrong

Apex Class :

```
public void retrieveBundleInfo() {
Map<Id, Product_Quantity__c> mapBundleToProduct = new Map<ID, Product_Quantity__c>();
Map<String, PriceBookentry> mapProductIdToPriceBookentry = new Map<String, PriceBookEntry>();
List<Product_Quantity__c> tempPQList = new List<Product_Quantity__c>();

for(GroupWrapp GW : grpWrappList){
    GW.totalCost = 0;
    for(BundleWrapper BW : GW.ListBundleWrapper){
        tempPQList = [select Id,Discount__c,Sale_Price__c,Margin__c, Quantity__c, Quote_Bundle_Product__c, Product__c, group__c, Bundle__c,Extended_Price__c,Part_Number__c,Cost__c from Product_Quantity__c WHERE Bundle__c =: BW.TempBundleselection.Bundle__c];
        BundlePQListWrapper bundlePQListWrapper;
        BundlePQListWrapperList = new List<BundlePQListWrapper>(); 
        for(Product_Quantity__c PQ : tempPQList){
            BW.BundlePQListWrapperList = BundlePQListWrapperList;
            GW.totalCost += PQ.Cost__c;
        }
    }
    Calculation();
}
}

public pagereference Calculation(){
List<GroupWrapp> tempGroupWrappList = new List<GroupWrapp>();

for(GroupWrapp GW : grpWrappList){

    GW.GroupTotalDiscount = 0;
    GW.TotalMargin = 0;
    GW.TotalExtendedPrice = 0;

    for(BundleWrapper BW : GW.ListBundleWrapper){

        for(BundlePQListWrapper BPW : BW.BundlePQListWrapperList){

            //Here i am getting the entered Discount only and i am trying to get all discount total here 
            GW.GroupTotalDiscount += Integer.ValueOf(BPW.BundlePQ.Discount__c);

        }

    }

    tempGroupWrappList.add(GW);
}
grpWrappList = tempGroupWrappList;
return null;
}

 public class GroupWrapp{
 Public Integer Index{get;set;}
 public Group__c WrappGRP{get;set;}
 public List<BundleWrapper> ListBundleWrapper{get;set;}
 public List<ProductWrapper> ListProductWrapper{get;set;}
 public Integer GroupTotalDiscount{get;set;}
 public Decimal totalCost{get;set;}
 public Integer TotalExtendedPrice{get;set;}
 public Integer TotalMargin{get;set;}

  public GroupWrapp(){
      WrappGRP = new Group__c();
      ListBundleWrapper = new List<BundleWrapper>();
      ListProductWrapper = new List<ProductWrapper>();

  }
  }   

public class BundleWrapper {
public List<Product_Quantity__c> BundlePQList{get;set;}
public product_Quantity__c TempBundleselection{get;set;}
public List<ProductWrapper> ListBundleProductWrapper{get;set;}
public List<PriceBookEntry> BundleProductPBEList{get;set;}
public List<BundlePQListWrapper> BundlePQListWrapperList{get;set;}

public BundleWrapper() {
    BundlePQList = new List<Product_Quantity__c>();
    TempBundleselection = new Product_Quantity__c();
    ListBundleProductWrapper = new List<ProductWrapper>();
    BundleProductPBEList = new List<PriceBookEntry>();
    BundlePQListWrapperList = new List<BundlePQListWrapper>(); 
}
}

public class BundlePQListWrapper{
public PriceBookentry BundlePQListPBE{get;set;}
public Product_Quantity__c BundlePQ{get;set;}

public BundlePQListWrapper(){
    BundlePQListPBE = new PriceBookentry();
    BundlePQ = new Product_Quantity__c();
    BundlePQ.Quantity__c = 1;
    BundlePQ.Discount__c = 0;
}
}

public class ProductWrapper {
public PriceBookEntry PBEList{get;set;}
public product_Quantity__c TempProductSelection{get;set;}

public ProductWrapper() {
    PBEList = new PriceBookEntry();
    TempProductSelection = new Product_Quantity__c();
}
}
```

Here is My Visualforce Page :

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote" extensions="AddGroupForQuoteController" sidebar="false">

<apex:form id="theForm">
<div>
<apex:pageMessages />
<apex:pageBlock title="Quote Detail">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton styleClass="buttonStyle" style="width:100px;" value="Save" action="{!Save}" />
        <!--<apex:commandButton styleClass="buttonStyle" style="width:100px;" value="update" action="{!UpdateValues}" rendered="{!IF(Quote.Id != Null, True, False)}"/>-->
        <apex:commandButton styleClass="buttonStyle" style="width:100px;" value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}" rendered="{!IF(Quote.Id != Null, True, False)}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:outputPanel >
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Quote Information" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.Name}" required="False"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.OpportunityId}" required="False"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.ExpirationDate}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.IsSyncing}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.AccountId}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.Status}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.Description}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Prepared For">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.ContactId}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.Phone}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.Email}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.Fax}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Address Information" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.BillingName}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.ShippingName}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.Billingcountry}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.Shippingcountry}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.Billingstreet}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.Shippingstreet}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.Billingcity}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.Shippingcity}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.BillingState}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.ShippingState}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.Billingpostalcode}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.Shippingpostalcode}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Bottom">
        <apex:commandButton value="Add Group" action="{!AddGroup}" reRender="theForm" oncomplete="ExtraTDhide();"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Quote Line Item By Group" columns="2">
        <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.Price_Book__c}" label="Select PriceBook" required="True"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:repeat value="{!grpWrappList}" var="G" rendered="{!grpWrappList.size > 0}">
    <apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Add Product" action="{!AddProduct}" reRender="theForm" oncomplete="ExtraTDhide();">
                    <apex:param name="ProductIndex" value="{!G.Index}"/>
                </apex:commandButton>
                <apex:commandButton value="Add Bundle" action="{!AddBundle}" reRender="theForm" oncomplete="ExtraTDhide();">
                    <apex:param name="ProductIndex" value="{!G.Index}"/>
                </apex:commandButton>
                <apex:commandButton value="Add SubGroup" action="{!addSection}" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!G.WrappGRP.Name}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:outputPanel >
                    <apex:repeat value="{!G.ListBundleWrapper}" var="QL" rendered="{!G.ListBundleWrapper.size > 0}">
                        <!--<apex:pageBlockSection title="Select Bundle" >-->
                            <apex:actionRegion >
                                <apex:outputLabel value="Bundle Name :" />
                                <apex:inputField value="{!QL.TempBundleselection.Bundle__c}">
                                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="relatedBundleInfo" action="{!retrieveBundleInfo}" immediate="false" oncomplete="ExtraTDhide();"/>
                                </apex:inputField>
                                <apex:pageblockSection id="relatedBundleInfo">
                                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!QL.BundlePQListWrapperList}" var="B">
                                        <apex:column headerValue="Product Name">
                                            <apex:outputField value="{!B.BundlePQ.Product__c}"/>
                                        </apex:column>
                                        <apex:column headerValue="Part Number">
                                            <apex:outputField value="{!B.BundlePQ.Part_Number__c}"/>
                                        </apex:column>
                                        <apex:column headerValue="List Price">
                                            <apex:outputField value="{!B.BundlePQListPBE.UnitPrice}"/>
                                        </apex:column>
                                        <apex:column headerValue="Discount">
                                            <apex:outputPanel >
                                                <apex:inputfield value="{!B.BundlePQ.Discount__c}">
                                                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="Bsaleprice,totalGroupDiscount" action="{!Calculation}"/>
                                                </apex:inputfield>                                                    
                                            </apex:outputPanel>
                                        </apex:column>
                                        <apex:column headerValue="Sale Price">
                                            <apex:outputPanel id="Bsaleprice">
                                                <apex:outputField value="{!B.BundlePQ.Sale_Price__c}"/>
                                            </apex:outputPanel>
                                        </apex:column>
                                        <apex:column headerValue="Quantity">
                                            <apex:outputPanel >
                                                <apex:inputfield value="{!B.BundlePQ.Quantity__c}">
                                                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="BexPrice,Bmargin,totalMargin,total" action="{!Calculation}"/>
                                                </apex:inputfield>
                                            </apex:outputPanel>
                                        </apex:column>
                                        <apex:column headerValue="Extended Price" >
                                            <apex:outputPanel >
                                                <apex:outputfield id="BexPrice" value="{!B.BundlePQ.Extended_Price__c}"/>
                                            </apex:outputPanel>
                                        </apex:column>
                                        <apex:column headerValue="Cost">
                                            <apex:outputField value="{!B.BundlePQ.Cost__c}"/>
                                        </apex:column>
                                        <apex:column headerValue="Margin" >
                                            <apex:outputfield id="Bmargin" value="{!B.BundlePQ.Margin__c}"/>
                                        </apex:column>
                                        </apex:pageblocktable>
                                </apex:pageblocksection>
                            </apex:actionRegion>
                        <!--</apex:pageBlockSection>-->
                </apex:repeat>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4">
                    <apex:outputLabel />
                    <apex:outputLabel style="display:block;width:590px;"/>
                    <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Group total Discount :  " />
                    <apex:outputPanel >
                        <apex:inputText id="totalGroupDiscount" value="{!G.GroupTotalDiscount}" />
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <apex:outputLabel />
                    <apex:outputLabel />
                    <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Group total price :  " />
                    <apex:outputPanel >
                        <apex:inputText id="total" value="{!G.TotalExtendedPrice}"/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <apex:outputLabel />
                    <apex:outputLabel />
                    <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Group total cost :  " />
                    <apex:outputPanel >
                        <apex:inputText id="totalCost" value="{!G.totalCost}"/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <apex:outputLabel />
                    <apex:outputLabel />
                    <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Group Margin :  " />
                    <apex:outputPanel >
                        <apex:outputText id="totalMargin" value="{!G.TotalMargin}%"/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="3" id="AllTotal">
    <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;width:100px;" value="Total :  " />
    <apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:outputText value="{!Total}"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputLabel style="display:block;width:850px;"/>

    <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Discount :  " />
    <apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:outputText value="{!Discount}"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputLabel />

    <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="SubTotal :  " />
    <apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:outputText />
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputLabel />

    <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Group Total :  " />
    <apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:outputText />
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputLabel />
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: You need to make few adjustments in your code to make it conform to the [best practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/01/apex-best-practices-15-apex-commandments.html) so you don't break any [platform limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm).
Kindly go through the articles and make changes in your code, and if you find yourself in hot-waters again, you can **update** this question or post a new one.

Comment: @Mahmood thanks for reply !! i am stuck with the single Bundle values only and still getting the same..see my updated post (i've put comment on the method where i m getting confused)

Comment: Can you please elaborate your requirement in bullet form for easy understanding for the community. In those requirement do explain the relationships between objects.